# More than one div in the same row

Tags: html, css

I want to develop three divs in the same row like this:

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Float or flexbox. Give it a go!

Comment: Expanding on @jedifans' comment: **`float`** *pros* - most (possibly all; I might be wrong) browsers compatible, safe; *cons* - may require some fiddly "clearfix"ing (GIYF), some consider it "old" (not sure why, it still works) | **`flexbox`** *pros* - modern, easy to use and manipulate grids; *cons* - cross-browser compatibility issues

Comment: Just stumbled across this: http://gridbyexample.com/ - might help you with creating a grid layout. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp also has a useful tutorial. In all fairness, I'm downvoting this question, as it does not appear to show any research into solving the problem beforehand; irrespective of showing any code, or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you could do that- thought I should share this with you. Check it out if this may help you.

1. Table layout:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box  
}
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
.wrapper .row {
  display: table-row;  
}
.wrapper .row div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #ddd;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Using Flexbox :

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box  
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
.wrapper .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.wrapper .row div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #ddd;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper .row div:before {
  content: '';  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Using Float :

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box  
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
.wrapper .row {
  display: block;
}
.wrapper .row:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.wrapper .row div {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #ddd;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 33.33%;
  float:left;
}
.wrapper .row div:before {
  content: '';  
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Good suggestion with the tables - always forget about that one! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<div><div style="height:40px; width:40px; float:left;">content1</div><div style="height:40px; width:40px; float:left;">content2</div><div style="height:40px; width:40px; float:left;">content3</div><div style="height:40px; width:40px; float:left;">content4</div><div style="height:40px; width:40px; float:left;">content5</div><div style="height:40px; width:40px; float:left;">content6</div></div>
```